# Cannot update an element in an object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

Have been trying to sort this for days and getting nowhere.

Have an array of objects in ReactJS in which I am trying to edit the element of one of the items in the array:

Structure of the object is as follows:

````
actor: null
​
aggregate: "Comment"
​
aggregateId: "5fcf206131414a05bcee9f88"
​
createdAt: "2020-12-08T06:42:41.983Z"
​
data: {…}
​​
comment: {…}
​​​
author: Object { id: "5ea683231fac57758ae7e4e2", nodeId: "MDQ6VXNlcjI1MTc0ODQ=", username: "monstertrux", … }
​​​
body: "ths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdf\n\nths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdf\n\nths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdfths is an edit testsfsdfsdf"
​​​
createdAt: "2020-12-08T06:42:41.983Z"
​​​
id: "5fcf206131414a05bcee9f88"
​​​
topicId: "5f3e3eb92db37843068c045a"
​​​
updatedAt: "2020-12-09T10:32:05.889Z"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
event: null
​
id: "5fcf206131414a05bcee9f88"
​
message: null```

have been trying to navigate the array and then edit the comment field with the following:
````

let itemToEdit = tempTimeline[foundIndex]
console.log(itemToEdit)

```
  itemToEdit = {...itemToEdit, data.comment.body: comment }
```

```
which pulls the item to be edited from the array and then tries to edit the data.comment.body element in the hierarchy.

But all I get for my efforts is the following errors:
No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'data'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.
',' expected.
Type '{ data: any; "": any; comment: string; id?: string | undefined; aggregateId?: string | undefined; aggregate?: string | undefined; event?: string | null | undefined; message?: string | null | undefined; actor?: Member | ... 1 more ... | undefined; createdAt?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IssueTimeline'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '(Missing)' does not exist in type 'IssueTimeline'.
',' expected.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify keys with dot notation, you'll need to go down through the levels like this:

```
const yourArray = [...];
const newArray = yourArray.map((item, idx) => {
    if (idx === indexToEdit) {
        return {
            ...item,
            data: {
                ...item.data,
                comment: {
                     ...item.data.comment,
                     body: comment,
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return item;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have actually tried that approach before and get an error at ...item.data.comment  of Object is possibly 'undefined'. Seems to be the same problem

Comment: You could use the nullish coalescing operator to handle that: `...(item.data.comment ?? {})`